# AS3 Error Code 1009 - Cannot access a property or method of a null object reference

Tags: actionscript-3, flash, apache-flex, object, dynamic

Yes, I'm sure there are millions of questions like this on SO, but this one has stumped me. Observe the code sample below:

```
<s:Group xmlns:fx="http://ns.adobe.com/mxml/2009" 
     xmlns:s="library://ns.adobe.com/flex/spark" 
     xmlns:mx="library://ns.adobe.com/flex/mx"
     creationComplete="init(event)">

<fx:Script>
    <![CDATA[
        import mx.events.FlexEvent;

        [Bindable]
        private var data:Object;

        private function init(e:FlexEvent):void {
            this.data.item = new Array();
        }
    ]]>
</fx:Script>
</s:Group>
```

Why can't I create an `item` array on the `data` object? I thought the `Object` class was innately declared as dynamic? Here is the error I get at runtime because of it:

```
TypeError: Error #1009: Cannot access a property or method of a null object reference.
```

Could someone please help me figure out how to create my own property on this object. Usually this is easy. lol

Thank you for your time.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The issue is that `data` has not been instantiated and is null.

```
<s:Group xmlns:fx="http://ns.adobe.com/mxml/2009" 
     xmlns:s="library://ns.adobe.com/flex/spark" 
     xmlns:mx="library://ns.adobe.com/flex/mx"
     creationComplete="init(event)">

<fx:Script>
    <![CDATA[
        import mx.events.FlexEvent;

        [Bindable]
        private var data:Object;

        private function init(e:FlexEvent):void {
            this.data = {};
            this.data.item = new Array();
        }
    ]]>
</fx:Script>
</s:Group>
```

Comment: Guess I've been awake too long today. Can't believe I missed that. Thank you.

Comment: You want to be careful with that... if data already exists, then you will be over-writing it with an empty object... which is not necessarily what you want.

Answer (score 2):

Make sure data exists first.

```
private function init(e:FlexEvent):void {
   this.data = {};
   this.data.item = new Array();
}
```

Comment: Yikes... I had a biiiiiiiggggg rush of "I can't believe I didn't think of that" run over me as soon as I saw that. Yep, that was it. Thank you. ;)

Answer (score 2):

Better still, you can do this:

```
private function init(e:FlexEvent):void {
    if(this.data == null) 
        this.data = {};
    this.data.item = new Array();
}
```

That way, whenever init is called, if data exists, it will not be overwritten with a blank object.

Answer (score 0):

You are confusing the data type and the data instance.  All classes derive from `object` though not all objects are dynamic.

In other words, if data is a data type that is not dynamic, then you can't set the `item` property.  Classes in AS3 are defined as dynamic with the `dynamic` keyword.  Anonymous objects are dynamic by default:

So, if you set `this.data = {}` then you will be able to set the `item` property.